# Cut String after second slash from left

Tags: java, string, path, cut, slash

I want to programm a PlugIn in Eclipse. Now i got a String back with a Path from a selected Project:

```
C:/Users/mbauer/abcde/efghj/klmno...
```

Now i would like cut the String in a Substring as followed:

```
C:/Users/mbauer/
```

The String should cutted after the 3rd slash from left. The Path should be dynamic for other users..

I tried:

```
String getPath = getSelectedProjectPath(dialog);
System.out.println(getPath.substring(0, 15));
```

But with the IndexOf 0 and 15 the Path isnt dynamic anymore, if a user with a longer name trying the plugin!

Answer (score 7):

I think that [`Path.subpath`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#subpath(int,%20int)) will do what you are describing:

```
System.out.println(
    FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(getPath).subpath(0, 3));
```

Comment: This is the right approach and perhaps the most elegant one

Comment: Which class do we need to import for this?

Comment: @VatsalSura `java.nio.file.FileSystems`.

Comment: if i consider this answer the string comes back as "Users\mbauer\runtime-EclipseApplication", the string get cutted after the "C:/" and the 4th slash, it cuts the 4th flash inclusive the first one...

Comment: @MBauer how about with [Berger's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38453430/3788176)?

Answer (score 3):

A regex like this would work :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String s1 = "C:/Users/mbauer/abcde/efghj/klmno";
    System.out.println(s1.replaceAll("((.*?/){3}).*", "$1"));
}
```

O/P : `C:/Users/mbauer/`

Comment: thank you a lot! that solved my problem! sorry for my bad english, i'm learning programming and i come from Germany! :-)

Comment: @MBauer - If you are dealing with "paths", then you should consider Andy's answer.. ywc btw

Comment: if i consider Andy's answer the Path get cutted after 'C:/' and after the 4th slash...

Answer (score 3):

As suggested in another answer, you may use `Path` and `Paths` from *java.nio.file* package.

Here is another way to use it :

```
Path path = Paths.get("C:/Users/mbauer/abcde/efghj/klmno");

System.out.println(path.subpath(0, 3).toAbsolutePath());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use indexOf() to search for the index of certain characters for example. In other words: you really want to do some prior research on how to search within strings; and how to possible manipulate them. There is plenty of documentation out there explaining such things. One more advanced way would be to use Java regular expressions resp. [patterns](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

But keep in mind: not all eclipse users are using Windows. You might have quite some people using Mac or Linux; thus your current approach will break on you very soon. So, instead of doing low level string operations; you should familiarize yourself with concepts like Java [Paths](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) in order to understand the abstractions you ought to use in order to create a reasonable plugin.

So, seriously: such kind of string search/manipulation is absolute basic stuff. Whereas creating eclipse plugins is really an advanced topic. Meaning: you are a beginner; so it might be better to step back for a while, and simply **learn** much more about the Java language; before starting to write eclipse plugins. Because chances are: given your current knowledge, you will create a lousy plugin that nobody will want to use.

Comment: Yeah i will keep in mind, but this is only for my other workers in my company and we all using eclipse only on windows, but thanks for your answer! have a great day!

Comment: Yeah, i didn't want program these Plugin, but thats a task from my boss, i should program a plugin to shorten tasks for my employee.. im in the 2nd year here in this company and nobody wants to program these plugin....

Comment: I see, but in the end, it doesn't make much of a difference. You will have customers using your product. And woha, these customers live next door, and they have direct access to your manager. Even more reasons for you to deliver a quality product. My personal two cent: whatever you do, find some experienced Java programmers around you to review your work (while you are working on it). Especially when you are more of a freshman in your company - the last thing you want is your name on a product that everybody is supposed to use ... and that doesn't work (good enough).

Comment: yeah i fully understand that, my boss is always behind my work and review the code all 2-3 days, to see if the code is structured and to see the PlugIn does work, but he said he know its really heavy to program an Eclipse Run Configuration with using groovy scripts and other stuff with right click in the Package explorer etc.. and im helpless here, nobody ever programs a PlugIn in our Company and i should.. but thanks for all your Words GhostCat! thanks for all the help, No one masters anything without hard work! Have a great day!